# Overriding Default "SET" function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-typescript

I have an AppContext that I'm using throughout. I create my variables like so:

```
const [ user, setUser ] = useState<User | undefined>(undefined)
```

Then set it in my AppContext.Provider with the values.

I call upon then as standard:

```
const { user, setUser } = useAppContext();
```

This works perfectly. However, what I want to do is, if we call setUser, I want another part of my app to show a loader and go away and load something.

Can I "override" the "setUser" before I set it in my AppContext? I'm fairly new to React.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I realise now that this is a daft question; in the parts that I want to update, I'll use the same `const { user } = useAppContext()` which will update as required and re-render.